# Copying normals in Geometry Nodes similar to data transfer modifier

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

[Blender 3.6.1]

I would like to make a Geometry Nodes setup that blends the normals in between objects to get an effect similar to this setup of modifiers:[image]

To be more specific, the goal is to have each ball's vertices that are closest to the ground copy it's normals, but with diminishing intensity the further each vertex is.

I've tried following the top answer of this post:
*[Blending normal with Geometry Nodes for an effect similar to data transfer modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266210)*,
but with the advent that some of the nodes in that solution have been replaced with newer ones (transfer attribute), and me not being an expert in geo nodes, I can't seem to replicate it properly or find a more up-to-date solution.

**How would I make a geo nodes setup that achieves this effect?**

Comment: This might be the solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276087/where-is-transfer-attribute-in-3-4

Comment: @quellenform thank you for your response. I have tried to create a node setup that copies normals, with the sample nearest and sample index nodes from your link. But I am definitely missing something, and I'm not sure where to go from here. https://i.imgur.com/jKLfwqF.png

Comment: @quellenform did you found a solution for this problem?